# Linking R with intel MKL 11.01.117

Tags: r, intel-mkl

I cant't seem to get them linked, the dynamic linking instructions seem to be outdated. Does anyone have any insight on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There has been activity on the rdevel list: [This posting from earlier this year](http://markmail.org/search/?q=r-devel%20list%3aorg.r-project.r-devel%20mkl%20intel#query%3ar-devel%20list%3aorg.r-project.r-devel%20mkl%20intel%20date:201205%20%20page:1%20mid:45d5z3p56nwcihdh%20state%3aresults) reports that at least one person has had success with R 2.15.0 and MKL 2011-sp1. Whether that applies to your version, I am unable to say.